# How to use ThreadPool class

Tags: c#

```
namespace ThPool
{
    class Program
    {
        private static long val = 0;
        private static string obj = string.Empty;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread objThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(IncrementValue));
            objThread1.Start();
            Thread objThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(IncrementValue));
            objThread2.Start();
            objThread1.Join();
            objThread2.Join();

            Console.WriteLine("val=" + val + " however it should be " + (10000000 + 10000000));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void IncrementValue()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                Monitor.Enter(obj);
                val++;
                Monitor.Exit(obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I use `ThreadPool` class in replacement of thread & monitor?

Comment: Hi huda
Can you please format this a little better?

Comment: remember to guard your worker methods' interior with try-catch because exceptions in worker threads just silently kill the thread

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to use the thread pool. For your task, you should look at the following.

- If you just need a task to run the easiest way is to use `QueueUserWorkItem`, which simply takes a delegate to run. The disadvantage is that you have little control over the job. The delegate can't return a value, and you don't know when the run is completed.
- If you want a little more control, you can use the `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` interface of delegates. This schedules the code to run on a thread pool thread. You can query the status via the `IAsyncResult` handle returned by `BeginInvoke`, and you can get the result (as well as any exception on the worker thread) via `EndInvoke`.

To use the `Enter`/`Exit` on `Monitor` properly, you have to make sure that `Exit` is always called. Therefore you should place your `Exit` call in a finally block.

However, if you don't need to supply a timeout value for `Enter`, you would be much better off just using the `lock` keyword, which compiles into a proper set of `Enter` and `Exit` calls.

Comment: You can use an AutoResetEvent or ManualResetEvent to determine when the run is completed (as in pablito's answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
EventWaitHandle[] waitHandles = new EventWaitHandle[2];


for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    waitHandles[i] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
    {
        EventWaitHandle handle = state as EventWaitHandle;
        for(int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref val); //instead of Monitor
        }
        handle.Set();
    }, waitHandles[i]);
}

WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
Console.WriteLine("val=" + val + " however it should be " + (10000000 + 10000000));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx).  It takes a delegate that is run on the threadpool thread, passing in a state object.

i.e.

```
string fullname = "Neil Barnwell";
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + (string)state);
}, fullname);
```

Don't be confused by `Control.BeginInvoke()`.  This will marshal the call to the thread that created the control, to prevent the issue where cross-thread calls update Controls.  If you want simple multi-threading on a Windows form, then look into the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeginInvoke`, `EndInvoke`. It uses the threadpool behind the scenes but it is easier to program. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the thread pool for anything but the most simple things. In fact it is extremely dangerous to aquire a lock on a thread pool thread. However you can safely use the Interlocked API's.